# Confirmation email with devise gem in Ruby on Rails 4 - Error:undefined local variable or method `confirmed_at' for #<User:0x007fa52bb0ea50>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have followed the steps in https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Add-%3aconfirmable-to-Users however I receive the error: **NameError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create undefined local variable or method `confirmed_at' for #** when i submit the signup form. How would I go about creating a confirmation email with the devise gem in Ruby on Rails 4? As well as what other requirements are needed? Here is what my code currently looks like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :pins
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :email, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+edu)\z/ }    
end
```

---

```
class AddConfirmableToDevise < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table(:users) do |t| 
      t.confirmable 
    end
    add_index  :users, :confirmation_token, :unique => true 
  end
def self.up
    add_column :users, :confirmation_token, :string
    add_column :users, :confirmed_at, :datetime
    add_column :users, :confirmation_sent_at, :datetime
    # add_column :users, :unconfirmed_email, :string # Only if using reconfirmable
    add_index :users, :confirmation_token, :unique => true
    # User.reset_column_information # Need for some types of updates, but not for update_all.
    # To avoid a short time window between running the migration and updating all existing
    # users as confirmed, do the following
    User.update_all(:confirmed_at => Time.now)
    # All existing user accounts should be able to log in after this.
  end

  def self.down
    remove_columns :users, :confirmation_token, :confirmed_at, :confirmation_sent_at
    # remove_columns :users, :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you make the necessary migrations to add confirmable module to User?

[Devise Confirmable Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Add-%3aconfirmable-to-Users)

Edit: I edited your Rails migration to this:

```
class AddConfirmableToDevise < ActiveRecord::Migration


def up
    add_column :users, :confirmation_token, :string
    add_column :users, :confirmed_at, :datetime
    add_column :users, :confirmation_sent_at, :datetime
    # add_column :users, :unconfirmed_email, :string # Only if using reconfirmable
    add_index :users, :confirmation_token, :unique => true
    # User.reset_column_information # Need for some types of updates, but not for update_all.
    # To avoid a short time window between running the migration and updating all existing
    # users as confirmed, do the following
    User.update_all(:confirmed_at => Time.now)
    # All existing user accounts should be able to log in after this.
  end

  def down
    remove_columns :users, :confirmation_token, :confirmed_at, :confirmation_sent_at
    # remove_columns :users, :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable
  end
end
```

Comment: When i follow the steps from the Devise wiki, I receive an error "uninitialized constant AddConfirmableToDevise" when i execute rake db:migrate on the last step. Any ideas? @paulorcdiniz

Comment: Can you post the migration here?

Comment: I acknowledge your efforts, however, it did not work. Any other ideas @paulorcdiniz ?

Comment: Same as before: NameError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create
undefined local variable or method `confirmed_at' for #<User:0x007fb1ed26a4c0> - @paulorcdiniz

Comment: It looks like the migration didn't run correctly. This error occurs because the User model doesn't have the 'confirmed_at' attribute, even tough the migration has the following line: 'add_column :users, :confirmed_at, :datetime'. Can you confirm the migration ran, and the user model has this attribute?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51142/discussion-between-paulorcdiniz-and-user3159229)

Comment: You saved my life!
I fixed a terrible bug with this line in a single migration
`User.update_all(:confirmed_at => Time.now)`